# Python extract all unordered list from a web page

Tags: python

Hello guys I use this code to get the html code of a web page.
I need to extract all the unordered list tag from it... what is the faster and simpler method?

```
#test.py
import requests
req = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
print 'Response Code: ' + str(req.status_code)
print '\nResponse:\n' + req.text
```

Comment: Check out beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib, bs4

pages = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(your_url).read())
lists = pages('ul') # your list of unordered list elements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
li = soup.select("ul")

print li
```